# MongoDB: aggregating fields from arrays of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection called Events, containing baseball games.  Here is an example of one record in the table:

```js
{
    "name" : "Game# 814",
    "dateStart" : ISODate("2012-09-28T14:47:53.695Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a1b24de3f25f4443d9747e"),
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "team" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c940b"),
            "teamName" : "Reds",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a1b24de3f25f4443d97480"),
            "score" : 17
        }, 
        {
            "team" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c938d"),
            "teamName" : "Yankees",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a1b24de3f25f4443d9747f"),
            "score" : 12
        }
    ]
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need help writing the query that returns standings for all teams.  The result set should look like:

```js
{
    "team" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c938d"),
    "teamName" : "Yankees",
    "wins" : <<number of Yankees wins>>
    "losses" : <<number of Yankees losses>>
    "draws" : <<number of Yankees draws>>
}
{
    "team" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c940b"),
    "teamName" : "Reds",
    "wins" : <<number of Reds wins>>
    "losses" : <<number of Reds losses>>
    "draws" : <<number of Reds draws>>
}
...
```

Here's the query I've started with...

```js
db.events.aggregate(
    {"$unwind": "$stats" },
    { $group : {
        _id : "$stats.team",
        gamesPlayed : { $sum : 1},
        totalScore : { $sum : "$stats.score" }
    }}
);
```

... which returns results:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c93cb"),
            "gamesPlayed" : 125,  // not a requirement... just trying to get $sum working
            "totalScore" : 1213 // ...same here
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a11a44a8de6dd8375c955f"),
            "gamesPlayed" : 128,
            "totalScore" : 1276
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a11a44a8de6dd8375c9661"),
            "gamesPlayed" : 152,
            "totalScore" : 1509
        }, 
....
```

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Using this query:

    'db.events.aggregate(
        {"$unwind": "$stats" },
        { $group : {
            _id : "$stats.team",
            gamesPlayed : { $sum : 1},
            totalScore : { $sum : "$stats.score" }
        }}
    );
`
I'm able to get results like this:

    {
        "result" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53a11a43a8de6dd8375c93cb"),
                "gamesPlayed" : 125,
                "totalScore" : 1213
            }, 
     ...

But I'm unsure how to re-group, then figure out the winner/loser status of each game.

Comment: sorry for the formatting.  blerg

Comment: @user3662896 Can you edit your question to include the query you tried?  As you've seen, code in comments doesn't format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem advisable for you to keep your "wins", "losses", "draws" within your documents as you create or update them. But it is possible to do with aggregate if a little long winded

```js
db.events.aggregate([

    // Unwind the "stats" array
    { "$unwind": "$stats" },

    // Combine the document with new fields
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "firstTeam": { "$first": "$stats.team" },
        "firstTeamName": { "$first": "$stats.teamName" },
        "firstScore": { "$first": "$stats.score" },
        "lastTeam": { "$last": "$stats.team" },
        "lastTeamName": { "$last": "$stats.teamName" },
        "lastScore": { "$last": "$stats.score" },
        "minScore": { "$min": "$stats.score" },
        "maxScore": { "$max": "$stats.score" }
    }},

    // Calculate by comparing scores
    { "$project": {
        "firstTeam": 1,
        "firstTeamName": 1,
        "firstScore": 1,
        "lastTeam": 1,
        "lastTeamName": 1,
        "lastScore": 1,
        "firstWins": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$gt": [ "$firstScore", "$lastScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "firstLosses": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$lt": [ "$firstScore", "$lastScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "firstDraws": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$firstScore", "$lastScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "lastWins": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$gt": [ "$lastScore", "$firstScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "lastLosses": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$lt": [ "$lastScore", "$firstScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "lastDraws": {
           "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$lastScore", "$firstScore" ] },
              1,
              0
           ]
        },
        "type": { "$literal": [ true, false ] }
    }},

    // Unwind the "type"
    { "$unwind": "$type" },


    // Group teams conditionally on "type"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "team": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    "$type",
                    "$firstTeam",
                    "$lastTeam"
                 ] 
            },
            "teamName": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$type",
                    "$firstTeamName",
                    "$lastTeamName"
                ]
            }
        },            
        "owins": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$type", 
                    "$firstWins", 
                    "$lastWins"
                ]
            }
        },
        "olosses": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$type", 
                    "$firstLosses", 
                    "$lastLosses"
                ]
            }
        },
        "odraws": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$type", 
                    "$firstDraws", 
                    "$lastDraws"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},

    // Project your final form
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "team": "$_id.team",
        "teamName": "$_id.teamName",
        "wins": "$owins",
        "losses": "$olosses",
        "draws": "$odraws"
    }}

])
```

The first part is to "re-shape" the document by unwinding the array and then grouping with "first" and "last" for defining fields for your two teams.

Then you want to [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) through those documents and calculate your "wins", "losses" and "draws" for each team in the pairing. The additional thing is adding an array field for the two values `true/false` is convenient here. If you are on a pre 2.6 version of mongodb the [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) can be replaced with **`$const`** which is not documented but does the same thing.

Once you [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) that "type" array, the documents can be split apart in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage by evaluating whether to choose the "first" or "last" team field values via the use of [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/). This is a ternary operator that evaluates a `true/false` condition and returns the appropriate value according to that condition.

With a final [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents are formed exactly how you want.

Comment: Thanks Neil, this is great, and I appreciate the explanations.  I'll definitely consider moving the results into the doc as I create/update.